# Try until something works

Tags: python, exception

Is there a way to do the following in Python?

```
try:
  Thing1()
try_this_too:
  Thing2()
try_this_too:
  Thing3()
except:
  print "Nothing worked :-("
```

Note that if Thing1() succeeds, I don't want to do anything else.

Comment: If `Thing1()` is successful, do you want `Thing2()` to happen?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, no. If Thing1() is successful nothing else need be done. But I want to keep trying things until something works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for thing in (Thing1,Thing2,Thing3):
    try:
       thing()
       break  #break out of loop, don't execute else clause
    except:   #BARE EXCEPT IS USUALLY A BAD IDEA!
       pass
else:
    print "nothing worked"
```

Answer (score 4):

This extends easily to any number of functions:

```
funcs = (Thing1, Thing2, Thing3)

failures = 0

for func in funcs:
    try:
       func()
       break
    except Exception:
       failures += 1

if failures == len(funcs):
    print "Cry evrytime :-("
```

Comment: I prefer the for-else approach versus using a counter.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
  Thing1()
except:
  try:
     Thing2()
  except:
     try:
        Thing3()
     except:
        print "Nothing worked :-("
```

Comment: Naturally, but the point of the question is to try to avoid this kind of syntactic rat's nest.